# How to deal with in progress instalation that hold back any new installations? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, windows-registry, windows-installation

I simply need to install a program into my computer, but whenever I try to it says, "Another installation is in progress. You must complete that installation before continuing this one". When I looked up how to solve this, a post said:

On the Registry Editor (regedit.exe), navigate to the following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress
and delete the entries you can find.

I accessed this folder, but the only program there was (Default) REG_SZ
I tried to delete it and a pop up said something like, unable to delete value.
What do I delete, or how do I fix my original problem?

Comment: The solution for is to restart your machine

Comment: I have restarted the computer multiple times but it still shows up

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have not done this already, restart the computer.

If it still refuses to install after that, and the `InProgress` key is still there, delete the *key itself*. Do *not* do this without having restarted the computer first.